# Data recovery on Ubuntu on dual boot machine

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, hard-drive

I have a dual booted older machine (tower, not laptop) that has Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04 on it. The machine recently suffered some minor damage during transport on a trip I had to take. At first I was having trouble getting the monitor to work and so I had to cut power several times to the machine and it seems like that may have caused some damage to the boot process. Its now going to CMOS Setup Utility screen instead Grub2 like it always did before. I took it to a local computer repair store to see if they can create a backup of my hard drive. But I'm now thinking that since they probably don't have Grub2 on their machines, they won't be able to access the Ubuntu portion of the hard drive...

Is there a way to access the Ubuntu portion of the hard drive at all at this point?

Comment: A backup does not depend on Grub, it has nothing to do with Grub.

Comment: You can boot any live session and access all the contents of the drive from there (if said contents are accessible, i.e., not encrypted or damaged beyond repair). A competent engineer knows that and should have OS agnostic tools to do any backup.